# No space left on device with df /tmp

Tags: 16.04, disk

When I try to compile to code I get:  `/tmp/ccoG0kQe.s: No space left on device`

I have a problem with my device space.

When I run this command  `df /tmp`

I get this output

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p5  78612400 74596016         0 100% /
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: So... delete some files from /tmp/.

Comment: Your root filesystem is full. You may need a bigger partition. Or maybe you can remove some stuff so that there is enough space.

Comment: a good tool to cleanup your system is stacer. sudo apt install stacer .then run stacer and cleanup your system

Comment: It's worse than `/tmp` is full. Since you installed everything in a single partition, everything is full. Check for runaway processes, use `sudo du -sk /*` to look for huge files you're SURE you don't need.